# Aggregate house numbers to MIN and MAX while considering districts

Tags: mysql, sql, max, min

I would like to get the MIN / MAX house number, which is an easy task.

But there's a column containing a district.

**Original Data:**

```
Street Name | House Number | district
Hauptstr.   |          1   |    A
Hauptstr.   |          2   |    A
Hauptstr.   |          3   |    B
Hauptstr.   |          4   |    B
Hauptstr.   |          5   |    A
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Street Name | House number (FROM) |  House number (TO) |  district
Hauptstr.   |          1          |           2        |     A
Hauptstr.   |          3          |           4        |     B
Hauptstr.   |          5          |           5        |     A
```

**My Output:**

```
Street Name | House number (FROM) |  House number (TO) |  district
Hauptstr.   |          1          |           5        |     A
Hauptstr.   |          3          |           4        |     B
```

I am open to ideas and suggestions. Do I need a temporary table to process the addresses?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what database system?

Comment: Originally the data comes from a MaxDB (SAP) database. I am currently trying to use the suggested "FIRST" and "LAST"-Value in a MySQL database (4.7)

Comment: @user3433650 so your query should be runnable in MaxDB, right?

Comment: @jarlh this will produce the result he already manages to get, not the desired output he's trying to get

Comment: @EstebanP. Preferrably in MaxDB. MySQL is also possible.

Comment: @user3433650 does my edited answer help you in any way?

Comment: @user2877959, oops, read "my output" as "my wanted output"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in MySQL using variables.  It assigns a group to each row of adjacent street values:

```
select street, district, min(housenumber), max(housenumber)
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := if(@d = district, @grp,
                         if(@d := district, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                        )
             ) as grp
      from t cross join
           (select @d := '', @grp := 0) params
      order by street, housenumber
     ) t
group by grp, street, district;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working on an implementation of SQL that supports them, you can use analytics functions like `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` in the lines of (untested)

```
select streetname
      ,first_value(housenumber) over (order by streetname, housenumber partition by district) as from
      ,last_value(housenumber) over (order by streetname, housenumber partition by district) as to
      ,district
from table
```

EDIT: that query doesn't work but something along those lines should.

EDIT2: here is a (somewhat convoluted) way to do it

```
select *
from (
    select streetname
          ,district
          ,from_num
          ,coalesce(to_num,lead(to_num,1) over (partition by streetname order by housenumber)) as to_num
    from (
        select streetname
              ,housenumber
              ,district
              ,case when coalesce(lag(district,1) over (partition by streetname order by housenumber),'') <> district then housenumber end as from_num
              ,case when coalesce(lead(district,1) over (partition by streetname order by housenumber),'') <> district then housenumber end as to_num
        from table
        )
    where from_num is not null or to_num is not null
)
where from_num is not null
```

This was tested in DB2. I don't know MaxDB so you may have to adapt the syntax.
As for an explanation of what's happening:

1. In a first pass (inner-most subquery), I'm looking at first (i.e., when previous district was different than current) and last (i.e., when next district will be different than current) records of each district group ordered by street name and house number. If first, then I store the house number as 'from'; if last, I store it as 'to'
2. From that, I select only the first and last record of each group (i.e., those where either the 'from' or 'to' values are filled in. This nets me with 1 to maximum 2 records per group. For each record that does not have the 'to' value filled in, I fill it in with the one from the next record.
3. All that's left to do is select from this sub-result only those records that have both values filled in and, voila!

Comment: From the documentation, it appears neither MaxDB nor MySQL support windowing functions (`lead`, `lag`). While your approach is elegant, it won't work here. Sources: https://help.sap.com/viewer/58c8145174ef49c1b78fae156ce46f62/7.5.6/en-US/44d947dc90234428e10000000a155369.html, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems

Comment: @user2877959 Thank you very much for the input. Sadly, as markusk already said: Neither MaxDB nor MySQL support those functions. I was impressed to learn what other databases are able to do.